# Need a jQuery plugin that modifies a CSS

Tags: css, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I'm trying to create a page that allows a user to change the "look and feel" of the site.  I would like to use something similar to [jQuery's ThemeRoller](http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/) or [FireFox's Developer Tool](http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/developertool/).
I can't force the user to use Firefox and I don't need all the options that the ThemeRoller has.  I'm really only looking for header, background, font size and font type.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find a plugin that already did this. I used [Brosho](http://usejquery.com/posts/8/brosho-design-in-the-browser-jquery-plugin) to give me a base starting point.  Brosho basically set's "Brosho: css info" to the element using the attr method.  Then scans the entire document for Brosho to create the CCS to export.

Answer (score 1):

Try a Stylesheet Switcher, it can be as advanced as you want and this will give you a lot more control the simple Div targeting.

http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex9/stylesheetswitcher.htm

Comment: I'm looking for something that allows the user to create the CSS instead of choosing one.  This might to allow the user to demo it throughout the site though.

Answer (score 0):

If your concern is transferring fewer/smaller files and you really want to avoid jQuery UI, it would be quite easy to develop a small jQuery plugin to modify background, font-size/type, and some header stuff.

Since you ask about jQuery specifically, I assume you have some experience working with it. Check out the plugin authoring documentation at http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring

If you aren't worried about transferring fewer/smaller files, just use jQuery UI themeroller and ignore the features you don't want.

Answer (score 0):

Store the user's style attributes in a datastore (cookie or server based).  Then on each page of the site have something like the following if user's preferences are stored server-side:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("h1").css('color','<% =UsersHeaderFontColor');
  $("body").css('color','<% =UsersBodyFontColor');
  $("body").css('font-size','<% =UsersFontSize');
  $("body").css('font-family','<% =UsersFontFamily');
});
```

If you want to get from a cookie, then there's a nice jquery cookie plugin that would allow you to set/get cookie name/value pairs.

Comment: Thats not a bad idea.  I am using the Application Cache to hold the data.
I've never dealt too much w/ cookies.  I done some basic stuff but the data that I was storing wasn't too important/ secretive . I wouldn't want a hacker to modify the cookie and have links on the page direct them to another page......